# Manual WCF Channel creation - error

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I want to create WCF client directly from code:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/acquisition/production.svc");
var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IProduction>(binding, myEndpoint);

proxy = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

The problem is that following code throws exception:

> There was no endpoint listening at.

But when add reference do WCF test client, service is discovered properly and can be invoked withouy any errors:

[image]

Why manual endpoint doesn't work?

Comment: What do you see when you go to `http://localhost/acquisition/production.svc` in a browser?

Comment: Standard page served by wcf host library. When add reference via 'add -> service reference' everything works fine.